# tracking dividend payments automatically

Tags: dividends

I want to create a dynamic spreadsheet somewhere(maybe google docs) that will log my dividends that I receive.  I have stocks at Fidelity and Tradeking.  Currently I get an email every time I receive a dividend payment with the company name that paid the dividend.  I would like to get the amount paid as well.  Does anyone know of a way I can get this info automatically?  I was hoping there would be something with an API out there that I could use to grab it.  Something in IFTTT would be awesome!  I have asked both companies and didn't receive any help.  So I thought I would ask here to see if anyone knows something that I don't.

Comment: You could use iMacros to scriptmatically login to your brokerage accounts every night and download data. That's what I do w/ my bank account. An ugly solution, but it does work.

Comment: Never heard of these iMacros before.  I found the Firefox extension, is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes, that's the one!